# How to get devise to render javascript in rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, devise

I am trying to get devise to use a specific error template when there are errors. It is getting to the correct page, but it is trying to render the javascript as the layout itself.

Here is my application.rb layout_by_resource code:

```
def layout_by_resource
  if devise_controller? && !current_user.nil? && !current_user.role.nil? && (current_user.role == "superadmin" || current_user.role == "admin")
    "admin"
  elsif devise_controller? && !current_user.nil? && !current_user.role.nil? && current_user.role == "user"
    "user"
  elsif devise_controller? && current_user.nil?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => "layouts/errors", :layout => false, :locals => { :current_object => resource } }
      format.html { "application" }
    end
  else
    "application"
  end
end
```

Here is my devise form code:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :remote => true) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => "layouts/errors", :layout => false, :locals => { :current_object => resource } }
      format.html { "application" }
end
```

Replace the above code segment with:

```
respond_to do |format|
      # Show a neat html page inside the app's layout for web users
      format.html { render :template => "errors/#{status}", :status => status }

      # Everything else (JSON, XML, YAML, Whatnot) gets a blank page with status
      # which can then be understood and processed by the API client,
      # JavaScript library (on Ajax) etc.
      format.all { render :nothing => true, :status => status }
    end
```

If you want to create a separate template for it, you can do so and save it in `/errors/***.html` and then render it.

**OR,** you could handle the error on the client side using javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but none of those options will help since i need to render my errors.js.erb file when there is an error on the devise registration form.

Answer (score 0):

So, better late than never, I guess (but hopefully this will help anyone who stumbles upon this page via the Googles).

What I had to do to get Devise to properly render javascript was tell it not to render any sort of layout, ala:

```
render "fail.js", :layout => false
```

That did the trick, and now my JS fires as expected.